# Why does Yii QueryBuilder ignores offset()?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, query-builder

My query result with offset = 0 and limit = 10 is exactly one row.

When I use offset = 1 there should be no result.

But with a query like

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('f.deleted = 0 AND b.version = f.version');
$criteria->params = [];

if ($idUserAnswerer)
{
    $query->leftJoin('bar AS b', 'b.idF = f.id');
    $criteria->addCondition('f.idUserOwner = :idUserOwner');
    $criteria->params['idUserOwner'] = $idUserOwner;
}

$query->select('*')
    ->from('foo AS f')
    ->where($criteria->condition)
    ->bindValues($criteria->params);

$query->order('FIELD(t.type,
    ' . X::X_TYPE_ID_A . ', ' . X::X_TYPE_ID_B . ',
    ' . X::X_TYPE_ID_C . '), b.created_time, b.votes DESC');

$data = $query->limit(10, 2)->queryAll();
```

(Hint: I have to use `$criteria`, because I have to use [inCondition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805247/how-to-prevent-mysql-injection-when-using-mysql-in-clause-without-activerecord-i) at some point)

I still get this one row. But normally (when I do this query directly in my db) I should not get a result.

Any ideas why Yii spits out this one row?

Comment: try this `echo $query->getText();` let me know what is the output??

Comment: @bhushya u r right, there is no limit or offset in getText().

Comment: Does it solve ur  problem??

Comment: Nope - it just shows that limit() and offset() gets ignored and I do not know why. I tried to set it within criteria and with query builder functions - nothing helped.

Comment: try this `limit($limit, $offset=null)` I am sure it will work :)

Comment: I tried this as well and it does not work. Something else must be wrong. Because I realize that it ignores my order by as well. I will update my question - give me a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the query builder. You need a specific order, binding values should be done at the end of the query.

This is because Yii does a prepare statement when binding values. It then caches this statement. Then you append your order and limit to it. When you do the query, the previous cached statement is used, without the order and limit. I think this is by design.

So always bind the values last:

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$data = $query->select('*')
    ->from('tbl AS t')
    ->where('idCategory=:catid')
    ->order('id DESC')
    ->limit(2, 2)
    ->bindValues(array(':catid' => 151))
    ->queryAll();
```

Comment: Yes, it was the order - I had `limit` behind `bindValues`.

Answer (score 0):

try following I hope it will work...

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('*')->from('tblA')->limit(10,1)->queryAll();
```

> ref: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder#sec-8

Edit:

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('id, name')
    ->from('user')
    ->limit(10)
    ->all();

// which is equivalent to the following code:

$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('id, name')
    ->from('user')
    ->limit(10);

// Create a command. You can get the actual SQL using $command->sql
$command = $query->createCommand();

// Execute the command:
$rows = $command->queryAll();
```

Comment: I tried this as well and it does not work. Something else must be wrong. Because I realize that it ignores my order by as well. I will update my question - give me a minute.

Comment: It's the first time I see the usage (new \yii\db\Query()). Is this for Yii2 only and where is it documented.